# When user opens a website, how to offer to install an app if it is not installed?

Tags: android

I have a website and an Android app. When user visits the website from his Android device, I'd like to offer user a link to install this app, but only if the app is not installed yet. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can take a look at Barcode Scanner to get the details. It basically works something like this:

Step #1: Create a Web page on your Web site, with the "hey! you don't have my app! click this really shiny button to download it!". Make sure this Web page has a simple URL (e.g., does not rely upon query parameters). Have the shiny button link to the [appropriate Market URL](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent) or however you are distributing your app.

Step #2: Create an activity in your app and give it an `<intent-filter>` with the appropriate `<data>` element that says it will handle links to that URL. You will also need to give the filter the `BROWSEABLE` category and possibly the `text/html` MIME type.

Step #3: Have the activity do whatever you want it to do when the user clicks the link and the app is already installed. This may mean that your `<intent-filter>` goes on an existing activity instead of a new one -- I have no way to tell what your intended behavior is here.

---

**EDIT**

Here is the relevant `<intent-filter>` from Barcode Scanner:

```
<!-- Allow web apps to launch Barcode Scanner by linking to http://zxing.appspot.com/scan. -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="zxing.appspot.com" android:path="/scan"/>
      </intent-filter>
```

If you visit [the link](http://zxing.appspot.com/scan) in a regular browser, you get a Web page.

Comment: Thank you. It seems logical, but somehow I can't get it to work. for example, I have created intent filter for category BROWSABLE, action VIEW and data scheme "http", host "google.com" and mimeType "text/html". I have installed the app on the device and then tried to open a link to "http://google.com" when in a browser. The page loads normally, no intercept happens. Maybe I have missed something?